# Is it possible to take screenshots after x seconds?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

The thing is I want to write an app to capture audio and process it in the background with foreground service, start with a button on MainActivity and it's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66971115/how-to-start-two-foreground-services-android-at-the-same-time).
I want to add the ability to take a screenshot, I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462944/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-other-app-programmatically-without-root-permission), through which I found the example [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/FINAL/MediaProjection/andshooter).This template uses mediaproject to do it and whenever I press the icon to start it my MainActivity doesn't show up that the app will start running In the background,  right.
**Is there any other way to start screenshot from button on MainActivity(or how to continuous shooting screen)**,If possible I can completely capture the screen continuously.

PS:I searched but still don't know where to do it is probably because of using `onActivityResult`,

Here is the code that capture screen with mediaproject:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.commonsware.android.andshooter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private static final int REQUEST_SCREENSHOT=59706;
  private MediaProjectionManager mgr;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mgr=(MediaProjectionManager)getSystemService(MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);

    startActivityForResult(mgr.createScreenCaptureIntent(),
      REQUEST_SCREENSHOT);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode==REQUEST_SCREENSHOT) {
      if (resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
        Intent i=
            new Intent(this, ScreenshotService.class)
                .putExtra(ScreenshotService.EXTRA_RESULT_CODE, resultCode)
                .putExtra(ScreenshotService.EXTRA_RESULT_INTENT, data);

        startService(i);
      }
    }

    finish();
  }
}
```

**ImageTransmogrifier.java**

```
 package com.commonsware.android.andshooter;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Surface;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class ImageTransmogrifier implements ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener {
  private final int width;
  private final int height;
  private final ImageReader imageReader;
  private final ScreenshotService svc;
  private Bitmap latestBitmap=null;

  ImageTransmogrifier(ScreenshotService svc) {
    this.svc=svc;

    Display display=svc.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size=new Point();

    display.getRealSize(size);

    int width=size.x;
    int height=size.y;

    while (width*height > (2<<19)) {
      width=width>>1;
      height=height>>1;
    }

    this.width=width;
    this.height=height;

    imageReader=ImageReader.newInstance(width, height,
        PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2);
    imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(this, svc.getHandler());
  }

  @Override
  public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
    final Image image=imageReader.acquireLatestImage();

    if (image!=null) {
      Image.Plane[] planes=image.getPlanes();
      ByteBuffer buffer=planes[0].getBuffer();
      int pixelStride=planes[0].getPixelStride();
      int rowStride=planes[0].getRowStride();
      int rowPadding=rowStride - pixelStride * width;
      int bitmapWidth=width + rowPadding / pixelStride;

      if (latestBitmap == null ||
          latestBitmap.getWidth() != bitmapWidth ||
          latestBitmap.getHeight() != height) {
        if (latestBitmap != null) {
          latestBitmap.recycle();
        }

        latestBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapWidth,
            height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
      }

      latestBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
      image.close();

      ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      Bitmap cropped=Bitmap.createBitmap(latestBitmap, 0, 0,
        width, height);

      cropped.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);

      byte[] newPng=baos.toByteArray();

      svc.processImage(newPng);
    }
  }

  Surface getSurface() {
    return(imageReader.getSurface());
  }

  int getWidth() {
    return(width);
  }

  int getHeight() {
    return(height);
  }

  void close() {
    imageReader.close();
  }
}
```

**ScreenshotService.java**

```
package com.commonsware.android.andshooter;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.display.DisplayManager;
import android.hardware.display.VirtualDisplay;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.media.ToneGenerator;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjection;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;


public class ScreenshotService extends Service {
  private static final String CHANNEL_WHATEVER="channel_whatever";
  private static final int NOTIFY_ID=9906;
  static final String EXTRA_RESULT_CODE="resultCode";
  static final String EXTRA_RESULT_INTENT="resultIntent";
  static final String ACTION_RECORD=
    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".RECORD";
  static final String ACTION_SHUTDOWN=
    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".SHUTDOWN";
  static final int VIRT_DISPLAY_FLAGS=
      DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY |
      DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC;
  private MediaProjection projection;
  private VirtualDisplay vdisplay;
  final private HandlerThread handlerThread=
    new HandlerThread(getClass().getSimpleName(),
      android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
  private Handler handler;
  private MediaProjectionManager mgr;
  private WindowManager wmgr;
  private ImageTransmogrifier it;
  private int resultCode;
  private Intent resultData;
  final private ToneGenerator beeper=
    new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 100);

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mgr=(MediaProjectionManager)getSystemService(MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
    wmgr=(WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    handlerThread.start();
    handler=new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent i, int flags, int startId) {
    if (i.getAction()==null) {
      resultCode=i.getIntExtra(EXTRA_RESULT_CODE, 1337);
      resultData=i.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_RESULT_INTENT);
      foregroundify();
    }
    else if (ACTION_RECORD.equals(i.getAction())) {
      if (resultData!=null) {
        startCapture();
      }
      else {
        Intent ui=
          new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        startActivity(ui);
      }
    }
    else if (ACTION_SHUTDOWN.equals(i.getAction())) {
      beeper.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_NACK);
      stopForeground(true);
      stopSelf();
    }

    return(START_NOT_STICKY);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    stopCapture();

    super.onDestroy();
  }

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Binding not supported. Go away.");
  }

  WindowManager getWindowManager() {
    return(wmgr);
  }

  Handler getHandler() {
    return(handler);
  }

  void processImage(final byte[] png) {
    new Thread() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        File output=new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),
          "screenshot.png");

        try {
          FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(output);

          fos.write(png);
          fos.flush();
          fos.getFD().sync();
          fos.close();

          MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(ScreenshotService.this,
            new String[] {output.getAbsolutePath()},
            new String[] {"image/png"},
            null);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Exception writing out screenshot", e);
        }
      }
    }.start();

    beeper.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_ACK);
    stopCapture();
  }

  private void stopCapture() {
    if (projection!=null) {
      projection.stop();
      vdisplay.release();
      projection=null;
    }
  }

  private void startCapture() {
    projection=mgr.getMediaProjection(resultCode, resultData);
    it=new ImageTransmogrifier(this);

    MediaProjection.Callback cb=new MediaProjection.Callback() {
      @Override
      public void onStop() {
        vdisplay.release();
      }
    };

    vdisplay=projection.createVirtualDisplay("andshooter",
      it.getWidth(), it.getHeight(),
      getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi,
      VIRT_DISPLAY_FLAGS, it.getSurface(), null, handler);
    projection.registerCallback(cb, handler);
  }

  private void foregroundify() {
    NotificationManager mgr=
      (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O &&
      mgr.getNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_WHATEVER)==null) {
      mgr.createNotificationChannel(new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_WHATEVER,
        "Whatever", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT));
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder b=
      new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_WHATEVER);

    b.setAutoCancel(true)
      .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

    b.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
      .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
      .setTicker(getString(R.string.app_name));

    b.addAction(R.drawable.ic_record_white_24dp,
      getString(R.string.notify_record),
      buildPendingIntent(ACTION_RECORD));

    b.addAction(R.drawable.ic_eject_white_24dp,
      getString(R.string.notify_shutdown),
      buildPendingIntent(ACTION_SHUTDOWN));

    startForeground(NOTIFY_ID, b.build());
  }

  private PendingIntent buildPendingIntent(String action) {
    Intent i=new Intent(this, getClass());

    i.setAction(action);

    return(PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0));
  }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.commonsware.android.andshooter"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
      android:name=".ScreenshotService"
      android:exported="true" />

  </application>

</manifest>
```

In my application I simply copy the ScreenshotService ImageTransmogrifier file then run it from MainActivity as above.

Comment: This solution is not a real screenshot, but it creates a JPG of the `view` you are using for the code snippet. So if you use your root view element, you should be able to create a JPG from just your app at any point in time you want:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107527/android-save-view-to-jpg-or-png

Comment: @muetzenflo So is there a way to take a screenshot of what I mean is to say I turn on my application then press start to start the service running in the background, it will capture everything displayed on the screen then for until I go on and turn off the service

Comment: @muetzenflo Can you help me solve it? Please allow me to pay for this, how can I contact you?

Comment: ah I see, you dont want a "screenshot", you want a screenrecord. Sorry, I have no experience with that. But I can promise you that this is not something you implement in few days. Maybe google for an "OpenSource Android Screenrecorder" to get some ideas.

Comment: You mean you want to screenshot other apps? Without looking at the documentation, I'm guessing there's no way that's permitted, for security reasons.

Comment: I think it looks like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.enlightment.screenshot&hl=vi&gl=US) but instead of having to press a button it is set automatically after x seconds

Comment: @Tenfour04 the code that I post above does that and now how can I replace onActivityResult is there any other way to use mediaproject, my mean is to start the screenshot from my foregroundservice running and not when MainActivity.Does calling onActivityResult in MainActivity will make the app run in the background immediately?

Comment: You’re not supposed to call any of the functions that start with `on`. Those are called by the framework as part of the lifecycle.

Comment: I don't understand what `on` is,that means I can't put the screenshot function while it is okay (for continuous shooting)

Comment: @PhạmCảnh Did you found the solution for that? I am also looking this type of functionality. I want that when user first opens the application, background service starts automatically and take screenshot when phone's screen is active in every x seconds and upload it on some server.